# Monitor troubles

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, display

Let me start with telling you my machine.

Win 7 pro. dual monitor extended displays. main is 1680x1050 and secondary is 1280x1024. Both monitores are LCD.

Both monitors are over 2-3 years old.

Here is the problem:

Recently when i boot my computer the main monitor will briefly turn on and then turn off and NOT turn on again unless i do numerous things to it until it comes back on. The secondary monitor functions correctly. I was wondering if there was anything that i could do to save the monitor?

To fix the issue i usually unplug the monitor for a few seconds and plug back in, or turn it on and off, or restart the computer. It will also not come back on after the computer has went to sleep.

Once it is on it usually stays on until the computer turns the screen off... i have not experienced it turning off while in use.

Thanks

**New information regarding my problem:**

It happened again last night. So i tried the normal things to get it to turn on that i listed above. This time it would not turn on. I got new cables and tried that and it did not fix the problem. After some time swapping cables, turning it on and off again, unplugging it for a few seconds plugging back in, restarting computer... it finally decided to turn on and stay on for the rest of the evening. Does anyone else have any suggestions on what i might can do to fix the monitor? It is a really nice and large monitor and would hate to have to buy a new one... monitors are expensive.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried updating your video driver?

Comment: If you do 'detect' in display properties does the other monitor cut back on?  (I have a couple of LCDs almost a decade old with that problem.)

Comment: The video driver was updated about a month ago. And i have not tried the detecting monitors thing yet, will try soon. However this problem just started occurring, i have not had any problems with monitor detection in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually opened up the monitor today and saw that a couple of the capacitors are leaking. I am going to run to a store tomorrow and purchase a few replacements and see if this solves the issue. I am sure this is the problem. I will post my results here.

Replaced two capacitors that were bad in the monitor and everything is working fine now. I replaced them with capacitors that could store a higher value. They should be better for the monitor anyways.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried swapping the cables over so that the primary becomes the secondary & vice versa. This will tell you whether it's the monitor or the graphics card.

If the **same physical monitor** exhibits the problem then it's the monitor, but if the problem **moves to the other monitor** it's probably the graphics card.

**UPDATE**

From your comment it appears that the problem is with the monitor rather than the graphics card. Make sure that all video leads are well connected at both ends.

You may have to go out any buy a new monitor.

Comment: Will try this tonight to see if this is the problem. However, i doubt this to be the case, my graphics card is performing very well and have not had any problems with the card. Although, i will still see if this is the problem.

Comment: Tried this the other night. The secondary monitor works fine in the main port on the graphics card. I also tried swapping out cables with no success. Please see OP for additional information.

Comment: @prolink007 - it sounds like the monitor might be developing a fault.

Comment: @ChrisF: I am aware of that, i am mainly asking if there is a way that i can fix the issue before i have to purchase a new monitor.

Comment: @prolink007 - Sorry. It depends where the fault is. Have you got a TV repair shop local to you? They might be able to tell you whether it's repairable or not.

Comment: @ChrisF: I do and will consider that option. Did not consider tv repair shop. Thanks